# How many cusps of modular forms on $\Gamma_0(l^j)$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

My confusion comes from the following paper.

> Ahlgren, Scott, and Matthew Boylan. "Arithmetic properties of the partition function." Inventiones mathematicae 153.3 (2003): 487-502.

In the section 5 of this paper,
the authors construct 
\begin{align*}
f_{l,j}(z):=\frac{\eta^{l^j}(l^jz)}{\eta(z)},
\end{align*}
where $l$ is a prime number.
And use the formula of $\eta-$quotient,
they claim that
\begin{align*}
f_{l,j}(z)\in M_{\frac{l^j-1}{2}}\left(\Gamma_0(l^j),\left(\frac{\cdot}{l}\right)^j\right).
\end{align*}
I wonder why it isn't a cusp form.
Furthermore,
how many cusps does the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(l^j)$ have and how can I find all the equivalences of them?

I really need some help, and any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: Try Diamond + Shurman's book "A First Course in Modular Forms". They explain cusps of congruence subgroups in great detail.